# Extract shortcut icon path without expansion

Tags: powershell, icons, variable-expansion

I can use this to extract the icon path of a LNK file in `$path`

```
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($Path)
$iconPath = $shortcut.IconLocation -replace ',\d$', $Null
```

but the result is expanded. What I see in the LNK file properties for Edge is
`%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe`
but what the code produces is
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe`
I am gathering data, on Autodesk products actually, for use later in replacing their crappy icons. So I would really prefer to keep and store the EV and then expand it myself on each machine, so on the off chance of a machine with a different path things don't break. But so far I can't find a way, programmatically, to get at the icon path without the expansion. Am I missing something, or am I out of luck?

Comment: The [Shell Link Binary File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-shllink/16cb4ca1-9339-4d0c-a68d-bf1d6cc0f943) is known (although rather hard to understand and apply). Grab desired info from `Get-Content $Path -Encoding Byte  -Raw` (PowerShell 5)  or `Get-Content $Path -AsByteStream -Raw` (PowerShell 7).